# Subtracting scaled projection matrix from identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand what the following operation signifies.

$$
\rm W_n=I-2u_n u_n^H/u_n^Hu_n
$$

where I and $u_n$ is described in section 6.3.4.2.3 of [this](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/136200_136299/136211/12.03.00_60/ts_136211v120300p.pdf) document.

My question is, what does this above equation signify in the general sense(not specific to the beamforming application in the document)? An explanation with a diagram(for a equivalent 2 dimensional case) will be very helpful.

Comment: The transformation $W$ is the reflection along $u$ through the Hyperplane perpendicular to $u$. For example, if you take $u=(1,-1)$, this gives us the reflection through the line $y=x$.

Comment: See [Householder transformations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Omnomnomnom. So if it is just reflection on a perpendicular hyperplane, how does the scaling factor (2 in this case) affect W?

Comment: So, the columns of householder matrix are eigenvectors?

Comment: If we didn't have the scaling factor of $2$, then we'd have a projection. That is, the vector gets flattened into the Hyperplane instead of getting reflected through

Comment: The columns *are not* eigenvectors, as you can verify with my example